# How to convert array of NSCFString to Array of NSCFNumber in swift?

Tags: ios, casting, swift4, nscfstring, nscfnumber

I have fetched array (say contactNameList) from SQLITE which is array of NSCFString. I want to compare objects of contactNameList with array of Id(say bookIdArray) which is of Int type.Can anyone please guide me.
Help will be appreciated.Thank you in advance :)

Code:

```
let testDetail_Obj = OfflineDB()

ContactDataArray = testDetail_Obj.fetch_BooksFromSQLite()

    for i in 0..< ContactDataArray.count
    {
        let newItem: Any = ContactDataArray[i] as Any
        contactNameList.addObjects(from: [(newItem as AnyObject).value(forKey: "book_Id") as Any])

        print("contactNameList fetched from db = \(contactNameList)")
    }


bookIdArray = contactNameList    // tried this 

func loadBooks() {

    let v = Constant.DBHandler()
    v.clearDatabase()

    Alamofire.request(Constant.url.getAllBooksUrl, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .downloadProgress(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility)) { progress in
        }
        .validate { request, response, data in
            // Custom evaluation closure now includes data (allows you to parse data to dig out error messages if necessary)
            return .success
        }
        .responseJSON {
            response in switch response.result {
            case .success(let JSON):
                if let jsonResult = JSON as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                    // do whatever with jsonResult
                    let booksJson = jsonResult ["objects"]
                    print("jsonResult In loadBook= \(jsonResult)")
                    let realm = try! Realm()

                    for bookJson in booksJson as! [NSDictionary] {
                        let book = Book()
                        print(bookJson)
                        book.author = bookJson["author"] as! String
                        print("\(String(describing: jsonResult ["author"]))")
                        book.bookImg = bookJson["book_img"] as! String
                        book.bookName = bookJson["book_name"] as! String
                        book.desc = bookJson["description"] as! String
                        book.language = bookJson["language"] as! String
                        book.noOfChapters = bookJson["no_of_chapters"] as! Int
                        book.id = bookJson["id"] as! Int
                        book.timestamp = bookJson["timestamp"] as! String

            if bookIdArray.contains(book.id) {
                                // where, static var bookIdArray = [2,10]
                                book.isHidden = false

}}}}}}
```

I want to show i.e -> book.isHidden = false , for all books whose id is present in contactNameList.I have tried

bookIdArray = contactNameList

But not getting output as per requirement.

Comment: show the code you already have and what you tried

Comment: that code does not look like it would compile

Comment: @Milan Nosáľ  :  my code is as above. I have also tried to caonvert contactNameList array of different types but each time it shows array of NSCFString